# How to put html response received from XMLHttpRequest into an iframe in Angular7?

Tags: html, ajax, iframe, xmlhttprequest, angular7

Does anyone have an idea how to embed this XHR request's html response into an iframe in Angular7?

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var link =  document.querySelector('#frame');
    this.populateIframe(link, "https://localhost:5601/app/kibana", 
    [['Authorization', 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxx']]);
  }
    populateIframe(iframe: any, url2: any, headers: any) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url2);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = handler;
        xhr.responseType = "document";
        headers.forEach(function(header: any) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader(header[0], header[1]);
        });

        xhr.send();

        function handler() {
          if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
            if (this.status === 200) {
              iframe.src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(this.responseXML);
            } else {
              console.error('XHR failed', this);
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

This is my iframe

```
<iframe id="frame" width="100%" height="100%" src=""></iframe>
```

I am getting html response from XHR request but could not put it in iframe.
This line

```
iframe.src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(this.responseXML);
```

is not working.

Answer (score -1):

I added an iframe to may page

`<iframe #ifr>
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>`

Used `@ViewChild` to access the iframe
`@ViewChild('ifr') iframe: ElementRef;`

Set source of the iframe in `ngAfterViewInit` method

`this.iframe.nativeElement.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3Cstrong%3E%3Ci%3Etest%3C/i%3E%3C/strong%3E';`

It works just fine. There might be something wrong about accessing the iframe or the data you get as a response. The code you provided is not enough.

Comment: Answers should answer the question. If you can't reproduce the problem, then you should mention that in a comment.

Comment: @Buzzinga What should we assign to ```this.iframe.nativeElement.src```

Comment: @GowthamSadineni `this.iframe.nativeElement.src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(this.responseXML);`